# CSS multiple min-height: 100% sections, with sticky footer

Tags: html, css, height

I know there are lots of questions asking how to make a sticky footer and 100% min-height main containers. But how can I have multiple sections and make each one 100% min-height, while still pushing the footer below?

I have the following, the sections are fine, 100%, but the footer doesn't get pushed down.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
      html, body, .main-container{height:100%;}
      section{min-height: 100%;}
      .footer-container{height: 100px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header-container">
      <header>
        header
      </header>
    </div>
    <div class="main-container">
      <section>
        section
      </section>
      <section>
        section2
      </section>
      <section>
        section3
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-container">
      <footer>
        footer
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Corresponding jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S7h8s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working but had to change the layout:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
      html, body {height:100%;}
      section{min-height: 100%;}
      .footer-container{height: 100px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <header>
        header
      </header>
      <section>
        section
      </section>
      <section>
        section2
      </section>
      <section>
        section3
      </section>
      <footer>
        footer
      </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

The jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/S7h8s

Answer (score 1):

Sticky footer with Compass FTW! 
http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/layout/sticky_footer/